# Debian/Linux backup files changed by user

Tags: backup, debian, restore, clone

I would like to backup my server that is hosting a few websites in such a way that I can restore everything to the way it was from a fresh format.

I know that I should backup all the home folders and then probably my /etc/ folders.

Is there a way to figure out all the folders that are relevant for backup in that they were not automatically generated or installed from apt-get?

It would ideally restore all the users with their current passwords as well.

Basically, enough to clone the system but only copying configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, if it's going about Debian,  `debsums -ce` could show you changed configuration files.

Answer (score 4):

You will certainly be interested in an article that I posted recently on my blog about **important folders to backup** (for Ubuntu but also applies to Debian).

**It regroups common files that are usually changed by users. At least on a webserver.**

Here's a summary.

*If you look at the actual article, I've put commands related to each step.*

- **/home** entirely
- **/root** entirely
- **/usr/local** entirely (it commonly holds software manually installed by the sysadmin)
- **/etc** entirely, or see below.
- **/var** entirely, or see below.
- Backup **MySQL databases, users and privileges**
- **List of installed packages** using *dpkg --get-selections*
- **Diversions** in */var/lib/dpkg/diversions*

Also, for **/etc** and **/var**, you can be more specific:

- Backup **users, passwords and groups**:

  - users and passwords are in **/etc/passwd** and **/etc/shadow**
  - groups are in **/etc/group** and **/etc/gshadow**,

  **JUST take the lines containing users/groups that YOU created (usually they have a uid >= 1000)!**
- Backup **crontabs**, and **atjobs** `/etc/crontab`
   `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` `/var/spool/cron/atjobs/`
- Backup users' **email** `/var/mail/`
- **Websites** `/var/www`
- Backup **needed config files in /etc/**:

  - Apache2 vhosts
  - Networking configuration
  - Postfix configuration
  - Anything else you see in **/etc/** and you wish to keep...

**source:** [Things to remember to backup or copy when migrating servers](http://www.codealpha.net/600/things-to-remember-to-backup-or-copy-when-migrating-servers/) [codealpha.net]
**source:** Gilles and bofh's comments, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget /root and /usr/local.

In a typical setting, 90% of disk usage (not counting /home) will be from /usr, which is only supposed to contain distribution-installed data (save for /usr/local) that you do not need to backup. Storage is cheap, it's best to backup too much than not enough, so it's good to backup /etc and /var as a whole.

Comment: Thanks b0fh, I've updated my answer with your suggestion. I appreciate the comment.

Comment: There may be a couple of things of interest in `/var/lib/dpkg`, such as the list of packages you have installed (best saved with `dpkg --get-selections`), and any diversion you created manually (all diversions are in `/var/lib/dpkg/diversions`). Also (though usually not for a server machine) game saves in `/var/games`.

Comment: Alright Gilles, thanks, I've added those to the list!

Answer (score -1):

For your need Faubackup can help you out.Check this out.. ;) & It suits your requirement.

To install, As you said,

apt-get install faubackup

http://faubackup.sourceforge.net/ 
http://faubackup.sourceforge.net/man/faubackup.8.html